Blazor App Missing wwwroot/scripts Folder After dotnet publish in GitHub Actions
I’m building a Blazor WebAssembly app and deploying it to Azure Static Web Apps using GitHub Actions. My app relies on JavaScript files generated from TypeScript with gulp task, which places them in the wwwroot/scripts folder. Locally, everything works fine, but in the GitHub Actions pipeline, the scripts folder is missing from the final publish output.
Here’s my setup:
Github workflow job
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          submodules: true
      - name: Deploy to Azure Static Web Apps
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        env:
            ENABLE_MULTIPLATFORM_BUILD: true
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          action: "upload"
          app_location: "AppLocation"
          output_location: "wwwroot"
          app_build_command: "dotnet publish -c Release"

gulpfile.js
var paths = {
    entries: ["./Components/Canvas2D/Canvas2d.ts"],
    output: "./wwwroot/scripts",
};

gulp.task("default", function () {
    return gulp
        .src(paths.entries)
        .pipe(
            esbuild({
                outdir: "/",
                bundle: true,
                target: "es2015",
                format: "esm",
                sourcemap: true,
                minify: true,
            })
        )
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.output));
});

package.json has build instruction
"scripts": {
  "build": "gulp default"
}

In the logs I see that the gulp task is executed
> gulp default

[11:57:58] Using gulpfile /github/workspace/AppLocation/gulpfile.js
[11:57:58] Starting 'default'...
[11:57:59] Finished 'default' after 96 ms

But it is missing in the published app.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: error loading dynamically imported module: https://blazorapp.fun/scripts/Canvas2d.js


Update:
I build my app locally with act action runner
gulp task runner successfully but I do not find the output files in the destination folder.
The gulp task works correctly, but there are problems when I run it with the GitHub workflow

What does your Azure app service log stream show

@SirraSneha logs
I don't see any problems in the logs

I created a sample Blazor web app, deployed it successfully to Azure Static Web Apps, and can view the scripts after deployment.

Ensure the index.html file is generated and placed in the correct directory (i.e. wwwroot).

My gulpfile.js:
const gulp = require("gulp");
const esbuild = require("esbuild");

const paths = {
    entries: ["./Components/Canvas2D/Canvas2d.ts"],
    output: "./wwwroot", 
};

gulp.task("default", async function () {
    try {
        
        await esbuild.build({
            entryPoints: paths.entries,
            outdir: paths.output,
            bundle: true,
            target: "es2015",
            format: "esm",
            sourcemap: true,
            minify: true,
        });
        console.log("Build completed successfully");

        gulp.src('index.html') 
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.output));
        console.log("index.html copied to wwwroot");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Build failed:", error);
        process.exit(1);
    }
});

package.json:
{
  "name": "blazorappwithgulp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp default",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "Blazor WebAssembly project with Gulp for TypeScript to JavaScript compilation",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-esbuild": "^0.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "esbuild-wasm": "^0.24.2"
  }
}


Make sure you configure correct app_location and output_location.

Workflow file:
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          lfs: false
      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '16'

      - name: Clean npm cache and install dependencies
        run: |
          rm -rf node_modules
          npm ci  # Ensures fresh installation of dependencies
     
      - name: Install gulp globally
        run: npm install -g gulp-cli

      - name: Check Gulp version
        run: |
          npx gulp --version  
    
      - name: Run gulp build
        run: |
          npx gulp default  
     
      - name: Deploy to Azure Static Web Apps
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_RED_WATER_081F97E0F }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          action: "upload"
          app_location: "/" 
          output_location: "wwwroot"  

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_RED_WATER_081F97E0F }}
          action: "close"

I've successfully deployed the app to Azure Static Web Apps via GitHub Actions.

Now I can view the scripts after the deployment.


Thanks for your answer. Your workflow job installs nodeJs and executes gulp tasks, output_location references the wwwroot dir. May it will also work for me, but I have not just index.html, I have many components and project libs that I also need to build. So dotnet publish should be executed (ENABLE_MULTIPLATFORM_BUILD is used to have installed nodeJs and dotnet), but in the output directory files produced by the gulp task do not exist.

Also looking at your workflow I do not see the sense in installing nodeJs and running the gulp tasks since Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1 will detect package.json, and based on it will install NodeJs and run the build command specified in packaga.json
